# load resources to java in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, resources, load

I have loaded log4j.jar and properties file into Oracle as Java resources.
My java class in Oracle declares method for use with Java stored procedure.
When I run the java method it unable locate\load used resource (properties file)
Can you advise why it does not and how to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: please, add some more context. What are you trying to do - are you writing a java program and want to store a file in the database? Are you trying to load a file? Are you trying to run a stored procedure? What exactly does the error output say?

Comment: thanks. I have java class that runs perfectly standalone. I would put it inside Oracle to process data on tables and send messages with log4j to outside of Ora. I loaded log4j properties file as resource into Oracle. When I run class method via exec of Java stored proceude it warns that log4j has not been configured properly ie properties file has not been read. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED as following
seems oracle supports only getResource() or getResourceAsString() for resource load along standalone java had been using PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch().
The replacement of resource locator and property configure method onto URL-tied has solved my issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Does Oracle support loading entire jars as a resource? Does it automatically use the jars afterwards?